# How to save recorded sound in the Room database?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to make a sound recorder app and I want to use the Room database in this small project to make a list of recorded sounds. But how to save recorded sound in that database?
Does anyone have some idea, any example?

Comment: Don't use Room for this. Save the recording in your apps container and save a reference to the file in the container (ex: filename) in your database. Also, please ask yourself why you want to use Room

Comment: File container? I thought the room would be a good choice here.

Comment: `The Room persistence library provides an abstraction layer over SQLite to allow for more robust database access while harnessing the full power of SQLite.` Storing files in a SQLite database isn't common at all in mobile development. Just store the file like you would do normally.

Comment: @Zun My question to you. My application is a completely offline based application. Where the i can backup and restore data from one device to the next using the .db file. If I am going to put some recording voice on app, how can I backup db file along with audio file stored on the memory? How can I backup all files to one file when i tap the Backup button? So that the i can restore with the same file. And I don't want to back up the db-file and the audio recording separately and restore each file separately.

Answer (score 1):

Use MediaRecorder to do the audio recording.

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myRecording.3gpp"; // set path where you want to save your recording
File file = new File(filePath); 
MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(file);
```

Start Recording

```
 myAudioRecorder.prepare();
 myAudioRecorder.start();
```

Stop Recording

```
myAudioRecorder.stop();
myAudioRecorder.release();
myAudioRecorder = null;
```

Now after recording save `filePath` to your Room Database table. Also, you will need to add write storage permission.

Comment: My question to you. My application is a completely offline based application. Where the i can backup and restore data from one device to the next using the .db file. If I am going to put some recording voice on app, how can I backup db file along with audio file stored on the memory? How can I backup all files to one file when i tap the Backup button? So that the i can restore with the same file. And I don't want to back up the db-file and the audio recording separately and restore each file separately.

Comment: That's not what he asked.